# Bootstrap Toggle, ON OFF function

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

does anyone know tell me why this code is wrong? It only works when the key is ON, and if I select OFF JS function is not performed. Thank you all.

html:

```
<div style="display:block;">
  <iframe id="python_result" name="python_result"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="example">

  <form id="tgleq" method="GET" action="py.php" target="python_result">
    <input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" name="state">
    <input id="relay" type="hidden" name="relay" value="1">
  </form>
  <!--Ho fatto sei milioni di test ma non ne vengo fuori!-->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#toggle-event').change(function() {

        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
          // $("#aktiver").prop("disabled", true);
          $("#toggle-event").val("1");

        } else {
          // $("#aktiver").prop("disabled", false);
          $("#toggle-event").val("0");

        }
        document.getElementById("tgleq").submit();
      })
    })
  </script>
</div>
```

this is a php:

```
<?php
    $inputs = array(    
    'rele' => $_GET['relay'],
    'stato' => $_GET['state'],
    );
    $cmd = 'python relayvale.py '.$inputs['rele'].' '.$inputs['stato'];
    $results = shell_exec($cmd);
    echo $results;      
?>
```

and this the python:

```
#!/bin/bash
from socket import *
import sys
import time

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    sys.exit(2)

relay = str(sys.argv[1])
state = str(sys.argv[2])
data_send = "58011"

if int(relay) == 1:

    if int(state) == 1:
        data_send += "2000000016C"
    elif int(state) == 0:
        data_send += "1000000016B"

elif int(relay) == 2:

    if int(state) == 1:
        data_send += "2000000026D"
    elif int(state) == 0:
        data_send += "1000000026C"

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8888))
s.send(data_send.decode('hex'))
data = s.recv(4)
print(data.encode('hex'))
s.close()
exit()
```

Thank you all.